# Is it available to set checkSelfPermission on minimum SDK < 23?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

New runtime permissions in Android-M asking for minimum 23 API level, but I still need minimum 16 API level in my project.

[image]

So, how to make this code more forward-compatible?

Regards

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[Use `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29), [`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)), and [`ActivityCompat.shouldShowPermissionRequestRationale()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String)), from the `support-v4` library (v23 or higher). These are backwards-compatible; if you are running on an older version of Android, they will "do the right thing" (e.g., return `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` for `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`).

Comment: I use support v4 too and  ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,  Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED returns false on HTC Incredible with android 2.3.3. Any idea why ?

Comment: @Anonymous: Your `targetSdkVersion` needs to be 23 or higher.

Comment: it is.. minSdkVersion="7"  android:targetSdkVersion="23"

Comment: @Anonymous you might need to change your minSdkVersion to 23 also.

Comment: In my experience, on older versions (I'm testing with API v.7) the ``ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission`` does not return permission granted.

Answer (score 5):

Just Check your android version before get check permission:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
            }else{
              //Do Your Stuff
           }
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you dont want to use AppCompatActivity the way is described here
https://codemammoth.blogspot.gr/2016/06/how-to-invoke-checkselfpermission.html

You have to invoke the methods :)

Comment: Answer I needed!~ Tnanks, bro

Answer (score 1):

You can check the build version `if(Build.Version.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.MARSHMALLOW)`. And then handle marshmallow permissions in there, and handle the other versions otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

checkSelfPermission is available above sdk 23.

we can check the permission is available or not using package manager

```
public static Boolean checkpermissions(Activity activity) {


        PackageManager mPackageManager = activity.getPackageManager();
        int hasPermStorage = mPackageManager.checkPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, activity.getPackageName());


        if (hasPermStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // do stuff
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return false;
        } else if (hasPermStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // do stuff
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }else
            return false;
    }
```