# How to get permissions on runtime for older API versions?

Tags: android

So I've been trying to get started on a simple GPS application but at some point I'm required to ask for user permission on locationManager methods

```
if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        Latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        Longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    } //location
                } //locationManager
            } //isNetworkEnabled
```

I understand that there's a simple way to do it for API 23, but I'd like to target Android 4.0.

I've seen a documentation about it (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) but I just don't quite understand how to  apply it to my code. I know I'm supposed to use ActivityCompact and ContextCompact but I'm just not sure on how. Please help!

Comment: runtime premissions are only used for API > 23. For API< 23 premissions are granted while installing application

Comment: @VygintasB so in this case how is user permission asked for?

Comment: They are asked when the user clicks on `Install` on the Play Store.

Comment: If you're not targeting API> 23 you only need to write permission inside manifest

Comment: Runtime permissions are marshmellow thing

Comment: @PrerakSola I understand that's usually the case, but when I'm accessing locations through locationManager I'm supposed to explicitly check for permissions, which I can't do on runtime since I'm not using API 23 and don't know how to do it on below versions.

Comment: @VygintasB I understand that now, but that means I need to explicitly ask for permission in another way since I'm using a locationManager method that requires that. What I need to know is how to get this permission on API below 23.

Comment: There is no concept of *Runtime Permissions* for `API <= 23`. So specifying the location permission in manifest file is enough.

Comment: @MuriloRM In this case  you just need to check if permission is granted   [How can I check permission under API level 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428464/how-can-i-check-permission-under-api-level-23)

Comment: @VygintasB that did it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

As you pointed out, Android `API >= 23` added the new `runtime permissions`.

For **older API** *the user is promped to accept them all on installation*

like in the image below

[image]

You just need to add them in the `manifest` and nothing else :)

Comment: I don't understand why does Android Studio keeps telling me to explicitly ask for user permission on LocationManager methods though... Am I just supposed to ignore that?

Comment: Are you going to release this app **ONLY** for android 4.0? Post your build.gradle file please, so we can check it

Comment: Problem was solved by using permissionChecker, thanks for your time anyways.