# Make distinction in requested Android permissions based on the users Android version

Tags: android, permissions

I have created an app which amongs others show the SSID name.
Now with the latest android version, the user needs to set extra permissions (`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`) for my app to be able to get the SSID name.

Now that's all fine, but 1. these permissions are harder to get (I understand that I can't just ask for them but the user has to explicit go to the app-settings and accept the location permission) and, more importantly 2. I don't want to ask for those rights if the user is still on an old(er) version of Android and these extra permissions are not needed.

I have these settings

```
minSdkVersion 11
targetSdkVersion 26
```

so also very old Android versions can install my app, and now they also have to give the permission for the Android version they don't yet have?

I would like that only users on the latest version of Android have to give these permission, and users on older Android versions don't have to.

Is it possible to make this distinction in the manifest?

I've seen a reference to [Is it available to set checkSelfPermission on minimum SDK < 23?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615013/is-it-available-to-set-checkselfpermission-on-minimum-sdk-23) but that question doesn't talk about the manifest xml and that's what my question is about

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it available to set checkSelfPermission on minimum SDK < 23?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615013/is-it-available-to-set-checkselfpermission-on-minimum-sdk-23)

Comment: @RyanGodlonton-Shaw That question doesn't mention the manifest xml, and that's what I am asking for

Comment: Ok, then I don't think it's possible to do it in the manifest on its own.

Answer (score 1):

User won't have to go explicit to the app-settings, just check the Android version with

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= N
```

And if it is true, you should ask the permission with

```
Activity.requestPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode)
```

Then listen the result with Activity.onPermissionsResult.

Comment: And should I then just leave it in the manifest.xml? Because I thought that all the permissions in the manifest.xml are asked for to the user when he/she installs the app, so then also the users which are using an older version are asked for these permissions?

Comment: Yes, you should just leave in the manifest.xml. It doesn't mean app will ask this permission, just it can request the permission when needed.